# how does your standard security system work?

Tags: security-theater

Do they have lasers motion sensors etc.. more looking for the type of security system you would see in a basic house not rich / well endowed one.

Comment: This questions needs a lot more detail. What exactly are you talking about?

Comment: Security system for house?

Comment: Well.. probably?

Comment: Need so much more information needed please. Type of asset under protection? If it is a house, what type? Rural / city area? Owner / renter of the asset?

Answer (score 1):

On the typical consumer-end, there are no lasers or microwave sensors. Look at what a starter security package includes, I'm sure lots of companies will be happy to explain to you what they offer if you call and ask. There's an increasing number of DIY solutions available, which run the gammut of complexity, but i think you're asking more about a typical alarm service, like Brinks or ADT.

Typically you can expect:

- magnetic door open sensors on major egress points
- PIR detectors in common areas, entryways, and high-value locations
- a main control panel for setup/monitoring, by garage door or primary entrance
- 1-2 limited control panels for activation, panic, and monitoring
- an outdoor siren to alert alarm activation to the public
- a cellular modem to contact an alarm monitoring service
- monitoring video cameras that can push to owner's phones ($$)
- magnetic window open sensors and glass break sensors ($$$)